# I want to get the source code of a tumblr page that scrolls infinitely

Tags: android, tumblr

I want to create an an android app that collects and displays images from a Tumblr page. The problem is i cant navigate on the page as it adds new items when you get to the bottom of the page . Please how do i go about this. Help is needed

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to use the API to display Tumblr data: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 and something like: https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr to parse the JSON. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19446540/2312574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be much better off using a completely different strategy: use [the API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts).

HTML Scraping is not a good idea, because if the page changes for any reason, you'll have to rewrite your code. The API will allow you to access the underlying data with no sneaky stuff.

Comment: Thanks , I just need a tiny bit of more help. How do i add the Jumblr Api to my application. I have added some api (like twitter4j and facebook) but the Jumblr is quite different especially for eclipse environment

Comment: I haven't ever used it but you'll probably need to import the src to eclipse then reference it as a library in your project build path.

Comment: Actually, it's probably easier to use the [.jar file](http://tumblr.github.io/jumblr/build/jumblr-0.0.6.jar) they provide.